# count number of characters in nvarchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datalength

Does anyone know a good way to count characters in a text (nvarchar) column in Sql Server?
The values there can be text, symbols and/or numbers.

So far I used `sum(datalength(column))/2` but this only works for text. (it's a method based on datalength and this can vary from a type to another).

Comment: `TEXT` is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Comment: "but this only works for text" how so? Everything that goes in an `nvarchar` column has to be, at the end of the day, composed of sequences of unicode characters, stored as UTF-16, and your method counts how many of those characters there are.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can find the number of characters using system function `LEN`.
i.e.

```
SELECT LEN(Column) FROM TABLE
```

Comment: 'LEN' will give you the count till 4000 only. So, how you will get the count of characters greater than 4000 in length?

Comment: I didn't get you... I guess it counts string value more than 4000 length. Please confirm.

Comment: hi @TechDo, I have an HTML content and using your solution i have tried to get length of the content which is more than 4000 charcters but dont know why it returns lenght as 4000 only!So, i said..!any idea about this?

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE There is no character limit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Comment: Yes! i agree! but by SQLserver allow me not more than 4000 charcters! do we need to do any setting in Management studio?

Comment: I tried in MySQL as well, and it says `#1305 - FUNCTION sampleDB.len does not exist` when I did so. And using `length` instead of `len` worked.

Comment: FYI, in postgres, this is `SELECT LENGTH(column) FROM table`.

Comment: would this also consider whitespace if it was included in the field?

Answer (score 13):

Use

```
SELECT length(yourfield) FROM table;
```

Comment: in DataBricks, ```length``` works ```len``` does not work

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`LEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) function:

> Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks.

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't `SELECT LEN(column_name)` work?

Answer (score 1):

text doesn't work with len function.

> ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version
>   of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead. For
>   more information, see Using Large-Value Data Types.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently, and here's what I did:

```
    SELECT
         columnname as 'Original_Value',
         LEN(LTRIM(columnname)) as 'Orig_Val_Char_Count',
         N'['+columnname+']' as 'UnicodeStr_Value',
         LEN(N'['+columnname+']')-2 as 'True_Char_Count'
    FROM mytable
```

The first two columns look at the original value and count the characters (minus leading/trailing spaces).

I needed to compare that with the true count of characters, which is why I used the second LEN function. It sets the column value to a string, forces that string to Unicode, and then counts the characters.

By using the brackets, you ensure that any leading or trailing spaces are also counted as characters; of course, you don't want to count the brackets themselves, so you subtract 2 at the end.